# ZF2 and Doctrine error

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

[image]

I'm using  ZF2 and Doctrine2
Please refer the screen shot , this error will show how to fix it ?

Comment: It would be better if you could copy and paste the error messages and stack trace (in addition to formulating your question better.) The text in this screenshot is impossible to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the future, Nimesha, I'd like to ask of you to not post Screenshots where it's not required. The error messages are clearly outlined by the Error Handler of Zend Framework 2 and Copy&Pasting the message into google - in this case at least - will easily get you to the results.

What you've done wrong is, you've forgotten to specify the namespaces / your doctrine driver. You can find an example configuration in the DoctrineORMModule /docs folder or [here on my Github](https://github.com/manuakasam/SamVersioning/blob/master/src/SamVersioning/Module.php#L48-L61)